# Same CursorLoader by extending activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cursorloader

I am trying to make a base activity to retrieve data from my content provider with it.I will retrieve the same data in a couple of activities. This is what I've been trying to do so far but I have a problem :

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projection =
                {
                        ActivitiesTable.KEY_EMAIL,
                        ActivitiesTable.KEY_ABOUT

                };
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, ContentProvider.ACTIVITIES_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.content.Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

}
```

and I'm trying to use it like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{
...
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
...
}
```

My problem is that in MyActivity, `this` doesn't get recognized as being `LoaderCallback` object. If I use the same line in my BaseActivity it will be seen as that. How can I initialize that `this` to be seen as one ?

Edit: I don't initialize the loader in the OnCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare that `MainActivity` also implements `LoaderCallbacks`:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...
}
```

No need to add the methods themselves - the ones that you got in `BaseActivity` will be called.

This setup will allow you to use different types of loaders across activities which extend `BaseActivity` (different types = different `loaderId` paramenters), while keeping the `LoaderCallbacks` method inside the `BaseActivity` itself.

Comment: The problem was that I was calling the `getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);` from a method that was posting to the server and it was detecting `this` as being something else, if I call it from OnCreate is fine. I'll just do it as you said and call the initLoader from the base activity.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, I did not mean that you should call `initLoader()` from `BaseActivity` - you can call it from the activities extending the base with different `loaderId`s, while handling the different types of loaders in the `BaseActivity`.